# Change led color for notification based on preference values

Tags: android

I have a preference fragment in which i have a list preference to change led color for notification.I have seven colors and i need to change the color of led based on my selection.How can i do this in program.

```
        <ListPreference
            android:entries="@array/ledcolors"
            android:entryValues="@array/updateledColors"
            android:key="prefUpdateLedColors"
            android:summary="Change led color.Only supported by your phone will work"
            android:title="Led Color" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are welcome to call [`setLights()` on your `NotificationCompat.Builder`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/NotificationCompat.Builder.html#setLights(int,%20int,%20int)) to request a particular color. You would need to convert whatever values you have in `@array/updateledColors` to `int` ARGB values for your desired colors.

Note that I have not seen an Android device support multiple LED colors in six years. This does not mean that such devices are nonexistent, just that they are uncommon. Having a user setting that may not work, depending upon what device they own, strikes me as being a bad idea from a customer satisfaction standpoint. Personally, I would never offer this feature to users.

Comment: @LincyLaiju: "is it a good option to remove that color change option from my app" -- I would remove that color change option from your app.